# Can one use regex to wildcard a set of whole words in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, wildcard, matching, words

This is nuts, I mean pseudocode, but something like this:

`/[January, February, March] \d*/`

Should match things like `January 13` or `February 26`, and so on...

---

WHAT I'M DOING:

```
my $url0 = 'http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal13.htm';
my $url1 = 'http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal14.htm';
my $url2 = 'http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal15.htm';
my $url3 = 'http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal16.htm';
my $url4 = 'http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal17.htm';
my $url5 = 'http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/sumcal.htm';

my $document0 = get($url0);
my $document1 = get($url1);
my $document2 = get($url2);
my $document3 = get($url3);
my $document4 = get($url4);
my $document5 = get($url5);

my @dates0 = ($document0 =~ /(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+/g);
my @dates1 = ($document1 =~ /(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+/g);
my @dates2 = ($document2 =~ /(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+/g);
my @dates3 = ($document3 =~ /(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+/g);
my @dates4 = ($document4 =~ /(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+/g);
my @dates5 = ($document5 =~ /(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+/g);

foreach(@dates0)
{
    print "$_\r\n";
}

foreach(@dates1)
{
        print "$_\r\n";
}

foreach(@dates2)
{
        print "$_\r\n";
}

foreach(@dates3)
{
        print "$_\r\n";
}

foreach(@dates4)
{
        print "$_\r\n";
}

foreach(@dates5)
{
        print "$_\r\n";
}
```

These printing gadgets give the following result: http://pastebin.com/7z13gBqt
This is not good:

http://tinypic.com/r/nqpapx/8

Comment: Want to get all the dates from http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/sumcal.htm and put'em in an array.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Use the DOM and get each TD element the date is in.

Comment: Trying to do something like `my $document0 = get($url0);` then `my $dates0 = ($document =~ /WHATEVER IT HAPPENS TO BE/g)`

Comment: @stackErr, I don't know how to do this DOM business. First time typing Perl.

Comment: read here on how to get a node from the DOM:http://search.cpan.org/~tjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm

Comment: Seriously... You should see that crazy shit I'm writing: http://pastebin.com/S39bu6LM

Comment: I would avoid regex for what you are trying to achieve if I was you, it will break if the date format changes. Its a lot easier to parse the Document Object Model and get each element that you need.

Comment: I'm just starting over... This code is ridiculous...

Comment: Oh, I see. It's like JavaScript.

Comment: `/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|etc) \d+/`

Comment: What is happening here: `my $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName ("CODEBASE");`

Comment: if the file has `<CODEBASE>some content here</CODEBASE><CODEBASE>some content here</CODEBASE>`. It will get an array of size 2 with boht the codebase elements

Comment: What? Then doesn't `$nodes` have to be `@nodes`?

Comment: I have to repeat that it is better to go through the DOM if you're page scraping. That way, there would be no surprises from dates in comments or that have some other purpose.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, maybe you could give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use an [*alternation*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters).

```
/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d*/
```

Would do that.

If you already have them in an array, then you can change the variable `$LIST_SEPARATOR` to *string* them into an alternation. And then parenthesize the whole

```
use English qw<$LIST_SEPARATOR>; # In line-noise: $"
my $date_regex
    = do { local $LIST_SEPARATOR = '|';
           qr/(?:@months) \d*/ # ?: if you don't want the capture
         };
```

This gives you a compiled expression, which you can reuse like so:

```
    my @dates;
while ( my $url = <DATA> ) { 
    my $document = get( $url );
    push @dates, [ $document =~ /($date_regex)/g ];
    push @dates, $date;
}
__DATA__
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal13.htm
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal14.htm
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal15.htm
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal16.htm
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal17.htm
http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/sumcal.htm
```

Comment: Your alternation gives this: http://pastebin.com/7z13gBqt That is, when I print out each of the array's contents.

Comment: @user3269763, can't see the paste bin. So I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: It doesn't capture the dates. It just captures the months.

Comment: @user3269763, I didn't know what you were trying to do. It *matched* the sequence you wanted. It also answered "whether you can wildcard a whole set of words". I made a change, I used a *grouping* parenthesis around the months and a capture around the entire expression you want to capture. When you did the global match, then it just gathered up the repeated captures, it doesn't automatically capture a portion of a string even if it *matches* it.

Comment: See the image at the bottom of the OP.